# How can I send a single email if found multiple records with same email address

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, email-studio

I have a data extension like below. Now when sending emails to the list it sends multiple emails to a single subscriber based on the record. As an example as - email1@example.com
is two times in the table so it sends two separate emails. I need to do two things -

1. Send a single email if there multiple records with the same email address.
2. Add all the details to a single email for a single user with multiple records.

Currently, I am using the below code and it shows all rows value in a single email for a similar email address. The output of the code is listed below -

```
email_address: email1@example.com
Row 1, firstName: Eileen, lastName: Dover
Row 2, firstName: Eileen, lastName: Dover
```

So it shows two different record values in a single email but it sends the email two times as there are two records for the email address - email1@example.com

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @i, @email_address, @user_code, @first_name, @last_name, @order_details

set @email_address = email_address
set @user_code = user_code

set @rows = LookupRows("TestDE","email_address", @email_address)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

output(concat("email_address: ", @email_address))

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @first_name, @last_name, @order_details
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @first_name = field(@row,"first_name")
    set @last_name = field(@row,"last_name")

    ]%% <br>
    Row %%=v(@i)=%%, firstName: %%=v(@first_name)=%%, lastName: %%=v(@last_name)=%%

    %%[

  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Here is the table structure -

| UserID | FirstName | LastName | OrderDetails | ItemNumber | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Eileen | Dover | abcdef | 01 | email1@example.com |
| 567890 | John | White | xyzuvv | 02 | email2@example.com |
| 123456 | Eileen | Dover | abrcdd | 03 | email1@example.com |
| 567890 | John | White | ertvvb | 04 | email2@example.com |
| 456789 | Jane | Banks | uerthy | 05 | email3@example.com |

So can anyone please help me to figure out the issue so that it will send a single email for all the records if there similar email address multiple times. Hope that makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. As I already wrote - it is limited how much you can do, by using ampscript, to prevent multiple emails being sent to the same recipient email address. I would instead recommend to query the data extension above, and deduplicate it into a new sendable data extension. You will just lookup all the records from the original one in your ampscript, while the sendout happens to the deduplicated one.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I am looking at your solution but I can't see the image you shared - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOKSo.png

Can you please share the image again as I need to check that.

Comment: Here is an alternative link for the image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FL5n9JavlBUOETbkfoqpxvjZmlDXP8Rb/view?usp=drive_link

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting the data set into two data extensions as shown below.

[image]

Then you can use AMPscript lookup to get the details of UserInfo records.

Join will be something like below

```
EmailRepository.UniqueId = UserInfo.EmailId
```

You can use the EmailRepository as the sendable data extension

Refer below for examples to AMPscript lookup

https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing how you are sending these emails. If you are using e.g. guided send in Email Studio, you have the option of deduplicating subscribers:

[image]

This will only send one single email to a specific email address, even if it is present multiple times in the sendable data extension under multiple subscriber keys.

Then, you could indeed use [LookupRows](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/), using email address as lookup criteria to include the details from multiple rows into a single email.

Comment: Hi Lukas, Thanks for your answer.

I have included more details with another questions if you can check - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/414141/send-only-a-single-email-for-multiple-records-with-similar-email-address-in-sale

Actually, I am developing the email and marketers are responsible for data extension options.

Thanks!

Comment: @MonowarHossain rather than posting a similar question, please update this one with this additional information